# Multiple instances of a symbol causing lag in Actionscript2

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2

Im trying to make a piano-based flash game similar to Synthesia. I've made multiple instances (char0, char1 etc.) of a symbol "char" & stored them in an array to denote the falling piano notes positioned at different places. The following is the collision detection code I am implementing between the notes & the keys.

But the lag increases with the more notes I include. As in, 120 FOR loop iterations slows down the game significantly.

```
for(var i = 0; i <120; i++){

_root.charac[i] = _root['char'+i];      //instances stored in charac array


    var ch = _root.charac[i];

    ch._y += 1;         //speed of falling notes



    if(ch._x>this._x && ch._x<this._x+this._width && ch._y>this._y && ch._y<this._y+this._height && !this.isBlack){


    _root.playSound(this);

 }

 }
```

Any way to optimize this code? Or is there any other way to store that many instances(notes)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have to many requests 120 of them, you would be better checking if 1 keys from all keys are hit instead of attaching an if statement to all and every key.

For example:
  if mouse down check which key was hit by alliterating through each key stored in an array..

Its a been a while and im not exactly how sure you have put your project together. Theory: you have 120 keys in an array...  on mouseMove get the position of the mouse x and y co-ordinates,on mouseDown(click)..compare the mouse x,y to the current key in the array x,y position.. by going through each key value in the array until you have a match... you have the key that was hit... now you have two events for all the keys...

Its the logic, similar to ray-casting in away

You shall get the idea: )

Comment: Can you please write a piece of code to demonstrate that? I've tried the hitTest method but it only increases the lag.

Comment: There is no use of Mouse in the game though. I just want collision detection between multiple instances of 2 symbols stored in 2 arrays (one with 88 static keys of piano & the other with 120 falling notes). When a note collides with a specific key, the sound attached to key plays.

Comment: Your idea is not going to work how you have it, also you may not have a mouse .x then use the falling notes, x or y position.... Think of the logic...you cant have 120 events attached....think of another way to achieve this :)

Comment: Yes Im aware 120 iterations are causing the lag, thats what I want to reduce. The operative logic in the above code is working fine, but its not optimized. If you can suggest some other logic, Im fairly new to as2 scripting so some code will help :)

Comment: can you upload your project file some where on-line and i could take a look at it, as i said its hard to address your issue as such cause i don't fully understand your layout etc